# How to pass this object of jquery into inner success function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

below is my code. I want to change the each mainimage src based on ajax call back.

```
jQuery('.xxx img[src*="mainimage"]').each(function() {
  vobj = $(this);
  var inmainurl = 'https://xxx.kki/api/oembed.json?url=' + $(this).attr('src');
  $.ajax({
    url: inmainurl,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
      $(this).attr('src', result.thumbnail_url); //this is not working.
    }
  });
});
```

below is not working

```
success: function (result) {                           
    $(this).attr('src',result.thumbnail_url);//this is not working.
}
```

how to achieve that?

Comment: check you browser console, image src change or not ?

Comment: What's result? A JSON? I'm not sure `this` is an image html object. Use `console.log($(this))` and `console.log(result)` to debug the code. You can see the results in the console.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your inner `$(this).attr` to `vobj.attr` does that solve your problem?

See that vobj is your defined variable.

Comment: No need for `$(vobj)`, just use `vobj` is enough, since it is jQuery object.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan you are very right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Note that this won't work as expected because the `vobj` variable is changed in each iteration, so the `success` handler in all requests will only access the last element of the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`$(this).attr('src', result.thumbnail_url);`

write

`vobj.attr('src', result.thumbnail_url);`

`this` is the function context and it is different for both functions, but the ajax callback has access to the vobj variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a closure in the loop, otherwise the `vobj` variable will have changed to the next element after the `$.ajax` call is made. You also need to use the `vobj` variable inside the `success` handler. Try this:

```
jQuery('.xxx img[src*="mainimage"]').each(function() {
    (function($el) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://xxx.kki/api/oembed.json?url=' + $el.attr('src');,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                $el.attr('src', result.thumbnail_url);
             }
        });
    })($(this));
});
```